# Impact on ODE solution of parameter change

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Let $\dot x(t) = f(x(t), \theta)$ be an ODE describing the evolution of a state $x \in \mathbb R^d$ with initial value $x(0)=x_0$. The function $f \colon \mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R^d$ depends on the state and on a $p$-dimensional real parameter $\theta$ that does not depend on time.

I would like to quantify the impact on the solution given by a change in the parameters. My approach would be to define $\epsilon = x' - x$ where $\dot x'= f(x'(t), \theta')$ for some $\theta' \neq \theta$, so that (omitting $t$) we have
\begin{align}
\dot \epsilon &= f(x,\theta)-f(x',\theta') \\
&= f(x,\theta)-f(x',\theta)+f(x',\theta)-f(x',\theta')\\
&= D_xf(x',\theta)\epsilon + D_\theta f(x',\theta')(\theta-\theta')+\text{higher order terms}.
\end{align}
From this, we see that a difference in parameters acts as an "excitation" for the deviation of the perturbed solution $x'$ from the true solution $x$.

I wouldn't know how to proceed from here. How would I get an indication on which specific component (or combination of components) of the parameter $\theta$ is most accountable, at least at first order, for deviations in the solution $x$? Is there any "standard" literature or computer algebra tools that would help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field of study here is termed "sensitivity analysis" and it is quite broad. For computing the sensitivity of an ODE solution trajectory to parameters $\theta$, there are generally two ways to proceed. One is analogous to "forward-mode" differentiation and is given by the sensitivity equations and the other is analogous to "backward-mode" differentiation and uses the adjoint equation.

#### Sensitivity equations

These are derived by directly differentiating the ODE with respect to $\theta$. Define the (local) sensitivities with respect to a single parameter $\theta_j$ by $S_{j} = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial \theta_j}\in\mathbb{R}^d$. We seek an ODE governing the time dynamics of $S_j$ obtained by differentiating the original equation. The sensitivity equation is given by $$\dot{S}_j = \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(x(t),\theta)}S_j + \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_j}\right|_{(x(t),\theta)}.$$
For each $j$, this coupled with the original ODE is now a coupled system of $d(j+1)$ ODEs the evolve the state $x$ as well as the sensitivities $S_j$ forward in time. Note that the initial conditions to the sensitivity equations are defined to be $0$ by the logic that the initial states $x_0$ are typically independent of $\theta$.

#### Adjoint sensitivity

Often times it is desirable to not compute the sensitivities of each component of $x$ at every time, particularly if $d$ is large or we are only interested in time-averaged or integrated dynamical quantities over some finite time $T$. For this purpose, we consider a scalar-valued functional $$G(x,\theta) = G(x(\cdot,\theta)) = \int_{t_0}^T g(x(t,\theta)\theta)~\mathrm{d}t.$$
The sensitivity of this quantity to $\theta$ can be determined by introducing an adjoint variable $\lambda(t)\in\mathbb{R}^d$ that solves an associated adjoint equation $$\dot{\lambda} = \left.\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right|_{x(t,\theta),\theta} - \lambda^\top\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_j}\right|_{(x(t),\theta)}, \quad \lambda(T) = 0.$$
Notice that the adjoint equation is a linear equation for $\lambda$ even when the original ODE is nonlinear. Also notice that it has a terminal condition (at $t=T$) instead of an initial condition. Since it also depends on the solution $x(t)$ at times $t\in[t_0,T]$, the state equation is solved forward in time for $x(t)$ (from $t_0$ to $T$), then the adjoint equation is solved backwards in time for $\lambda(t)$ (from $T$ to $t_0$).

Once the adjoint variable has been determined, the sensitivity of the functional to $\theta$ is given by $$\frac{\partial G}{\partial \theta} = \int_{t_0}^T \lambda^\top(t) \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\right|_{(x(t),\theta)} +\left.\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}\right|_{(x(t),\theta)}~\mathrm{d}t.$$
The use of $\lambda$ here is related to the Lagrange multiplier of a related optimization problem where you might want to minimize $G$ subject to the constraint that $x(t)$ follows the original ODE. This method is generally preferred for large systems as typically only some scalar functional such as a data misfit error term is investigated.

Both of these methods have advantages and disadvantages. Most of the literature in the field is computational in nature, although one may be able to actually work out some analytic forms for (extremely) simple ODE systems. This material as well as more statistical and computational methods are covered in the cited book. Books on optimal control or ODE-constrained optimization may also cover these topics.

Disclaimer: The author is my advisor.

*Smith, Ralph C.*, Uncertainty quantification. Theory, implementation, and applications, Computational Science & Engineering 12. Philadelphia, PA: Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics (SIAM) (ISBN 978-1-611973-21-1/hbk). xviii, 382 p. (2014). [ZBL1284.65019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1284.65019).